# split an URL which contains @PathVariable and @QueryParameter in java

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a list which contains some URLs :

```
daa/v1/{id1}/{id2}?d1=1&d2=2

daa/v1/{id}/id2/{id2}

daa/v1/{id}/id_c/{id2}
```

I have a call like this : daa/v1/1/2 and I want to match this call to a correct URL from list and extract parameters

```
How do I do this most efficiently?
```

Comment: In what context? Are you writing a server? A client? An analysis library?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
String[] values = url.split("\\?")[0].split("/");
id2 = values[values.length-1];
id1 = values[values.length-2];
```